# Error in scan() with backslash in line

Tags: r

I am running the following code with such error.

```
> rat <- scan("sortedratings.csv",nlines=760,sep=",",what=rat.cols,multi.line=FALSE);                                                       
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :                                                                         
  line 755 did not have 8 elements                                                                                                                    
>
```

And here is the line that is causing all the trouble

```
ubuntu@ip-10-28-6-239:/data/csv$ sed -n "750,760p" sortedratings.csv                                                                                  
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 17, 2011","","","KK9876",4,0                                                                                                 
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 17, 2011","","","Lyteskin45",4,0                                                                                             
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 17, 2011","","","Mrs. Felton",5,0                                                                                            
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 17, 2011","","","Nick Bartoszek",4,0                                                                                         
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 17,2011","","","SANFRANPSYCHO",5,0                                                                                          
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 17, 2011","","","Wxcgfduytrewjgf@!?$(:@&amp;&amp;$&amp;@\"",5,0                                                              
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 18, 2011","","","Downs58",5,0                                                                                                
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 18, 2011","","","kitty1019",5,0                                                                                              
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 18, 2011","","","Rj&amp;e",4,0                                                                                               
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 18, 2011","","","Robin Kinzer",5,0                                                                                           
"281656475","2.5.0","Jul 18, 2011","","","Roderick Palmer",5,0                                                                                        
ubuntu@ip-10-28-6-239:/data/csv$ s
```

I have tried different fixes but i can't figure out the correct one. Any idea?

i don't have a problem removing the backslash for no text or anything.

Oh, forgot to add, the file is 1.4GB big, so i can't read all the file or just replace it with sed, since it's just too big for my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Details" part of `?scan` (used by `read.table`, `read.csv` and so on):

```
 If ‘sep’ is non-default, the fields may be quoted in the style of
 ‘.csv’ files where separators inside quotes (‘''’ or ‘""’) are
 ignored and quotes may be put inside strings by doubling them.
 However, if ‘sep = "\n"’ it is assumed by default that one wants
 to read entire lines verbatim.
```

So it looks like your problem is the "escaped" quote `\"` in that line causing the trouble - R expects an escaped quote for a CSV to be a double quote `""`, not a backslashed quote `\"`.

I think your best bet here is to replace escaped quotes with double quotes, be it using Linux or in R (R example below):

```
txt <- readLines("tmp.txt")
txt <- gsub('\\\\"', '""', txt) # note the weird double backslashing because
                                # `readLines` adds extra backslashes
# if you `cat(txt, sep='\n')` you will see that the `\"` is now `""`
```

Then you can use `read.csv` or `scan` like before (note the `textConnection(txt)` which converts the string into a file-like object for `scan` to use):

```
read.csv(textConnection(txt), ...)
```

---

### Edit/Addition

Re OP's comment - the file is 1.4GB and there are difficulties reading it all into R at once, so how to do the sanitizing?

#### Option 1

You appear to be on Linux, so you could use `sed`:

```
sed -ire 's!\\"!""!g' myfile.txt
```

(Depending on where your data comes from, perhaps you could adjust the program that is outputting the data to output it in the format you require in the first place, but this is not always possible).

#### Option 2

If you are averse to using Linux or want an in-house R solution, use the `n` parameter to `readLines` to only read in a few lines at a time:

```
# create the file object and open it, see ?file
f <- file('tmp.txt')
open(f)
txt <- ''

# now read in 100 lines at a time, say
while (length(txt)) {
    txt <- readLines(f, n=100)
    # now do the sanitizing/coercing into a data frame, store.
    # ...
}
close(f)
```

Comment: Thanks. i forgot to mention but the file is 1.4GB, any idea how can I clean it up since I can't load the whole file into R?

Comment: You can use `readLines`' `n` parameter to only read in a few lines at a time. I've updated the answer to show how you might do this.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I ended up doing the following. First, split with linux, then sed, then join again. Thanks forthe ideas.